# What is the max number of characters that can be sent in an IM message with the Sinch SDK

Tags: sinch

I am looking to build an IM app using the Sinch SDK, but wanted to know what the max number of characters that I can send in a message is? Can't see that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t a fixed limit to how many characters can be included in a message. Messages will be split into multiple if size is too large, however we discourage from sending very large messages such as encoding images into headers…